# Crash 23.10 after freeze and flashing

Tags: lenovo, freeze

I hope anybody could help:
I’m not running any particular software (browser, Docs or PyCharm for example) and the screen freezes, goes black, comes out two three times and then stays frozen. Last time I left it flashing until the message appeared:

**dev sda clean files blocks**

It can't be a memory problem, here my specs:
Lenovo ThinkPad T14Gen 2a, AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 5850U with Radeon™ Graphics × 16
32GB Ram, 1TB SSD. I have ONLY Ubuntu installed (no dual or partitions).

If I remember well, it did happen only while working exclusively on the laptop (without external monitor. If these are on, laptop screen is off).
I have read few questions regarding the message and they all have problems while booting their system but I don't. When I boot the computer it does show the message but it loads perfectly. When it happens I end up force resetting the laptop.

Anybody could help? I have some exams where I need the laptop and I can't take the risk to "let's hope it doesn't happen".

Thanks in advance!